# Format SQL query by php implode function

Tags: php, mysql, database, implode, nette

I'm using Nette Framework and I have this commands in action:

```
    $id = is_array($id) ? implode(', ', $id) : $id;
    $this->database->table('manufacturing')->where('id', $id)->update(array('trash' => '1'));
```

When I select 4 rows in my Grid and call this action to delete items, it will generate this SQL code:

```
UPDATE `manufacturing` 
SET `trash`='1' 
WHERE (`id` = '31, 32, 33, 34')
```

But I need code like this to update all rows:

```
UPDATE `manufacturing`
SET `trash` = '1'
WHERE ((`id` = '31') OR (`id` = '32') OR (`id` = '33') OR (`id` = '34'));
```

Is possible to do with implode function? Thank you.

edit:
when I made this:

```
$id = is_array($id) ? implode(' "OR" ', $id) : $id;
```

it will do this:

```
UPDATE `manufacturing` 
SET `trash`='1' 
WHERE (`id` = '31 \"OR\" 32 \"OR\" 33 \"OR\" 34')
```

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ Nette, but I think you want to look for an option or alternative to `->where()` that allows you to do an `IN` clause instead of `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can directly pass the array in the where function, it will be transformed to a `id IN (1,2,3,xxx)` automaticaly.

Refs : http://doc.nette.org/en/2.2/database-selection#toc-filtering